# What is the Polars equivalent of Pandas `.isna()` method?

Tags: python-polars

I'm trying to replace Pandas with [Polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars) in production code, for better memory performance.

What would be the Polars equivalent of Pandas `.isna()` method? I couldn't find any good equivalent in the doc.

Comment: Note the distinction between missing values and floating point `NaN` values.

Missing values is likely the one you'll be needing most. That is `is_null` and floating point `NaN` is `is_nan`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polars has [.is_null()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Series.is_null.html?highlight=is_null#polars.Series.is_null). Note that Pandas has [.isnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html?highlight=series%20isnull#pandas.Series.isnull) as well, which is an alias for `.isna()`.

I.e., per the example linked above:

```py
s = pl.Series("a", [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, None])

s.is_null()
shape: (4,)
Series: 'is_null' [bool]
[
        false
        false
        false
        true
]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Should have seen that in the doc

Answer (score 0):

```py
import polars as pl

s = pl.Series("s", [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, float('NaN')])
s.is_nan()

shape: (4,)
Series: 's' [bool]
[
    false
    false
    false
    true
]
```

Same with numpy `ndarray`:

```py
s = pl.Series("s", np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, np.nan]))
s.is_nan()

shape: (4,)
Series: 's' [bool]
[
    false
    false
    false
    true
]
```